Hero & Heroine in Mysore on bus roof
Please help me to identify this Hindi Bollywood movie.
Plot: Hero is from poor/middle-class family, Heroine is a sister/daughter of a rich/bad guy. Both are classmates in college, initially they do not go along, but later they fall in love with each other. Father/Brother fixes heroine's marriage with his rich bad friend. Goons beat up hero. Hero/Heroine runs away from the city.
The Scene fresh in my mind=> Hero & Heroine are in Mysore (India), on top of a bus, travelling around city's tourist places (Palaces, Gardens) singing along. /scene.
Later in movie, bad guys again find them, hero fights with them in a garden type place, kills most of them (no weapons/guns). Father/brother changes mind, allows both of them to marry.
Few more facts:

We had this movie on VHS Cassette (maybe between 1995-2001).
Both Hero & Heroine were very new, not established/famous.
Hero did not get famous, Heroine got, from other movies.
Hero also had few college friends (& teacher), who also got beaten/tortured/killed by bad guys.
Movie's title is based on one of the song.


Answering my Own Question, because I remembered a few more details:
Movie: Mera Dil Tere Liye (1992)
Youtube Full Movie Link: 


More Details (in addition to my points in question):

Kadar Khan was also starring in this (I knew it, but yesterday I could not find this movie on his Wikipedia page.)
The heroine was Mamta Kulkarni (I found this movie name on her imdb page.)

Plot Summary (from imdb)

Priya R. Singh lives in a palatial house with her businessman dad, Raghunath, and housewife mom, Savitri. She attends college, meets with fellow collegian, Vijay Verma, and after a few clashes, both fall madly in love with each other. When Raghunath finds out, he is enraged, as he would like Priya to marry Vikram Singh, the U.S. settled son of his friend, Ajit Singh, all the more when Vijay lives in a hostel room and has no family roots. Priya refuses to obey her father's wishes, elopes with Vijay, and with the help of College Principal Sinha, both decide to get married in a simple temple ceremony. The wedding is interrupted by Raghunath who alleges that Priya is not yet 18, is still a minor under his care. As a result, this marriage is canceled, and Priya is taken home. Priya knows that she will complete 18 years of age in 15 days, what she does not know is that her dad plans to take her to the U.S. and forcibly get her married to Vikram, and there is no power on earth that will dare to stop him.
TL:DR; Rich girl meets poor boy in college, clashes, then falls in love with her. Father forces her to marry a rich NRI. Father & NRI beats hero. Hero & heroine escapes to Mysore. Bad guys catch up. Later Good Guy & Girl gets united.


you can accept your own answer as well.
